# Inputing directories/files into a text file and then showing files older than certain date

Tags: linux, bash, ls

I'm using "ls -alR" to input directories and files in those directories into another text file.

```
ls -alR > testalR.txt
```

text file is created like so:

```
./test-file_folders/test_folder_1:
total 400
drwx------ 5 "user" "group" "size" May 2 10:30 test_file_1
....     file info    ... more file info   ....test_file_2
...more files 


./test-file_folders/test_folder_2:
total 400
drwx------ 5 "user" "group" "size" Oct 2 11:35 test_file_1
....     file info    ... more file info   ....test_file_2
...more files
```

I am trying to show files that have not been accessed since October 2 2018.
I've tried:

```
`sed -n '/Oct 2 00:00/,/Oct/ 2 23:59/p' /testalR.txt
```

..but it produces no results. Is there a better way to display this or even possible?

Sorry, should have added this to begin with. I know using find -atime variant would be the best option. But we are using a system and a process that is bogged down by the find command. I am trying to find alternatives so using "find" can be avoided and wouldn't have to access directories directly each time I wanted to run a search.

Comment: See the use of `-exec ... {}+` in my answer in response to your concern about system performance when running `find`.

Comment: jj102, see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for details of why using 'ls -alR' is not a good approach for this problem.

Comment: jj102, I can't think of a reason why running `find` would make a system more "bogged down" than running `ls -alR`.  What `find` command have you run, and what makes you think that it is causing the system to be "bogged down"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing the output of `ls` is a slippery slope.

Use `find`:

```
find . -type f -atime +3 -print

find . -type f -atime +3 -exec ls -uld {} +
```

Using `-print` simply returns a list of the filenames.  Using `-exec ls -ld {} +` causes `ls` to be run for every file returned, giving you the details you may want.

The argument. to `atime` (or `mtime` or `ctime`) is in 24-hour steps.  The argument can be positive or negative (or zero).  Using `-atime +3` finds a files that have  been accessed at least FOUR days ago.

Using `-exec ... {} +` causes the command in "..." to be executed for every object returned, bundling as many objects (files) as possible at a time.  This is much more efficient than forking a process for every file returned, as with:

```
... -exec ls -uld {} \;
```

One way to limit your results to a specific date, is to create two reference points (files) like this:

```
touch -amt 201809302359 f1
touch -amt 201810012359 f2
find . -type f \( -anewer f1 -a ! -anewer f2 \) -exec ls -uld -exec {} +
```

Comment: If the atime and other options to find are not sufficient (e.g. you want a specific date no matter when you run the script), you can use the stat(1) command with find to get the times, then do a string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

try with find:

```
find /folder -atime +30
```

where +30 = days

others params: man find